# Is it possible to use Audacity as a simple sample editor?

Tags: audio, audacity, wav, resampling

It's a weird question but here's my workflow.

I want to be able to open a WAV file from other DAWs, like Ableton or Reason in Audacity. Apply some effects and maybe do some slicing, then get the file back into the "master" DAW.

Ableton has this option that allows you to use an external audio editor and, since I'm familiar with it, I'd like to use Audacity.

Here's the catch, Audacity always open the files as a project, meaning I need to export a WAV and worste, I'd need to know where the file is in my system.

If I could simply save it back to the opened WAV I could quickly get the file back in, and passing a batch processor through a bunch of samples becomes an easy task.

Anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Audacity has chosen not implement a direct overwrite feature, likely (at least in part) because it's able to load multiple files from multiple locations (similar to the DAW itself).